# Android : EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview, webviewclient

I have implemented WebView in Dialog Activity and I am loading simple url into 
webview.

my Webview settings are as

```
wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbView);
        wbView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wbView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wbView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wbView.setInitialScale(100);
        // wbView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wbView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wbView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

and MyWebViewClient() contains

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            prgBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                SslError error) {
            Log.e("Error VAGARO", error.toString());
            prgBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am loading two HTML files from the Asset in the same webview its working fine but unable to load dynamic url.

I Google and find some posts on 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21177

My logcat shows me

```
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1683)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7900(WebViewCore.java:926)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1795)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2917)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:593)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:984)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Suggest me the change that I should make.

**Update**

I found that if I'll pass any url like "www.facebook.com" then its giving me this error,
but if I'll replace it with "https://www.facebook.com" then its working fine.

Comment: You'll also see this error if you try to load a javascript: url into a nonexistant page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue I found was because of the url without `http://` or `https://`. So I appended this tag if the url doesn't contains `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: I just had the same issue on a Toshiba AT300 (Android 4.0.3) because of a trailing slash on the URL: http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/

Comment: I get the same problem. Using `WebView.loadUrl("http:///www.google.com");` works. However, as soon as I try `WebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html5video.html");` it shows the exception. /facepalm

Comment: @VishalKhakhkhar what about if need to load "HTML" type string ?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I fixed it by changing the order. I put the **loadUrl** before **getSettings()**

 Working snippet below,

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

// load file
mWebView.loadUrl(SERVER_URL);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this stack sometimes during the last days in my LogCat, but until now it wasn't blocking my dev. But I suspect it's related to the struggling my WebView somtetimes does.
It seems to be a Bug affecting not only us:

- [Android: removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up when url contains http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010939/android-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-webviewcore)
- [android EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140338/android-eventhub-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-webv)
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21305
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21177

---

[android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(int):void](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java#removeMessages)

```
1675        private synchronized void removeMessages(int what) {
1676            if (mBlockMessages) {
1677                return;
1678            }
1679            if (what == EventHub.WEBKIT_DRAW) {
1680                mDrawIsScheduled = false;
1681            }
1682            if (mMessages != null) {
1683                Throwable throwable = new Throwable(
1684                        "EventHub.removeMessages(int what = " + what + ") is not supported " +
1685                        "before the WebViewCore is set up.");
1686                Log.w(LOGTAG, Log.getStackTraceString(throwable));
1687            } else {
1688                mHandler.removeMessages(what);
1689            }
1690        }
```

The Queue `mMessages` has to be NULL to avoid the Exception.

```
// Message queue for containing messages before the WebCore thread is ready.
```

So it's quite simple: something is causing the WebCore to need much more time to set up.  According that 107 is `SET_SCROLL_OFFSET' and the stack-trace shows ZoomManger I will check if something in my code is causing the view to get active in some way while initiating the settings.

---

**ANSWER**:
This exception will be thrown if you call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` and then wait too long for calling `setContentView()`. How long you can wait I couldn't figure out. So those two will be the first lines in `onCreate()` from now. Time will show me if I'm right.

The good news are that this warning tagged `webcore` is only a warning and itself causes no impact to the rest of the app.

The bad news are that it seems that my problem has nothing to do with it and comes from somewhere other.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is generally related to the URL being pointed to not being found. It is a 404 (i.e. a URL that wasn't found). Modify the URL

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after I called `finish()` and restart the same `Activity`. Therefore, maybe it cannot simply finish the activity with a `WebView` . I did the following before finish the activity and it works.

```
try{
        webView.stopLoading();
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)webView.getParent();
        parent.removeView(webView);
        webView.destroy();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "clear webView fail");
        e.printStackTrace();
}
 finish();
```