# Unable to put log message in Android webkit native code

Tags: android, logging, webkit, native

I am trying to put log message in the native code of Web kit in Android.

I am using the approach used at [this page](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-framework@googlegroups.com/msg01674.html) to put the log.

I am getting the error mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10512282/682869).

I am testing my log by running an app containing a WebView, with the following code:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Since I am using "http://" in my URL, the solution from the referenced question isn't useful.

Can anyone suggest what changes must be made to successfully get Logs from native code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that the problem is in the native code of Webkit. Try to create an application for loading url in non-modified Android. I think you should get the same error.

As for me I use  `__android_log_print()` function to print log messages.