# android EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up

Tags: java, android, listview, webview

Hi am getting this error when i am launch the webview from listview activity.
See interesting thing is when i am try to launch webview two or three time it's work fine. After am getting this error. Please give me perfect solution .

All ideas are welcome

```
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1671)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7800(WebViewCore.java:920)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1783)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2858)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:586)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:977)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-30 18:53:06.966: W/webcore(20239):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512282/android-eventhub-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-we

Comment: Did you solve your problem?