# why do some java eclipse errors not have a specific line of code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This error has no line of code within my code that I see. How do I track down where the error is coming from? I found a link here to solve the problem but I just don't even know where to put the code, I have like 10000 classes, finding the problem manually doesn't sound fun. [Android : EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512282/android-eventhub-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-we)

```
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int         what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
  07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1869)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$8400(WebViewCore.java:978)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2061)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:3210)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:653)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1096)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 7-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 7-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 07-08 20:02:35.078: W/webcore(11122):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 105) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1869)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$8400(WebViewCore.java:978)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2061)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.WebView.sendViewSizeZoom(WebView.java:3430)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:659)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1096)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 07-08 20:02:35.088: W/webcore(11122):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It does have an exact line of code.  The problem is that your code isn't causing an immediate problem, its causing a problem later on when it tries to use some data you gave it.  No computer is smart enough to detect that- if it did we wouldn't need to write programs, they'd self-program.  Here it looks like you called something too early.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512282/android-eventhub-removemessagesint-what-107-is-not-supported-before-the-we)

Comment: you have 10,000 classes.  The JDK only has 3-4K

Comment: it's called exaggeration, obviously, i don't have 10000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally search your code for places where you're using a webview. Then check the URL you're passing. This error typically occurs when you are passing a URL to the webview without specifying the protocol.

For instance, change:
`stackoverflow.com/questions`

to

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions`